# Null Pointer Exception at Button's onClick

Tags: android

I have a form having one edittext and an autocompleteview. And a button to search things based on this form. In this form I can either give value in edittext and autocompleteview may be empty and vice versa. On this basis I have passed value of these view to another activity where I made a webservice call and then fetch result.

This is activity where these view are presents:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_section);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

    searchByNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchByNameEditText);

    searchByAddressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchByAddressEditText);

    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.selectStateSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_arrays));
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

    patientUtilityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.patientUtilityButton);
    patientUtilityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(PatientSectionActivity.this, patientUtilityButton);

            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.patient_utility_button_popmenu, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    String patientUtilityMenuItem = item.toString();
                    patientUtilityButton.setText(patientUtilityMenuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedStateValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });

    doctorName = searchByNameEditText.getText().toString();

    // Search Button
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!selectedStateValue.equals(" ") || doctorName.equals(" ")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(PatientSectionActivity.this, DoctorNameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("State Name", selectedStateValue);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (!doctorName.equals(" ") || selectedStateValue.equals(" ")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(PatientSectionActivity.this, DoctorNameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", doctorName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And in other activity, I get these extras from intent and make webservice call in AsyncTask but my app is crashing. Please any one help me as I am new in android.

This is my other activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class DoctorNameActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> doctorAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String doctorName;
    String selectedStateValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_name);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();


        selectedStateValue = intent.getStringExtra("State Name");

        doctorName = intent.getStringExtra("Name");

        if (!selectedStateValue.equals(" ") || doctorName.equals(" ")){
            FetchDoctorName fetchDoctorName = new FetchDoctorName();
            fetchDoctorName.execute(selectedStateValue);
        }else if (!doctorName.equals(" ") || selectedStateValue.equals(" ")){
            FetchDoctorName fetchDoctorName = new FetchDoctorName();
            fetchDoctorName.execute(doctorName);

        }

    }


    private class FetchDoctorName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchDoctorName.class.getSimpleName();

        public String[] parseDoctorName(String jsonString) throws JSONException{
            final String DOCTOR_NAME_ARRAY = "name";
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(DOCTOR_NAME_ARRAY);

            String[] doctorNamesResult = new String[array.length()];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length(); i++){

                String doctorName = array.getString(i);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, doctorName);

                doctorNamesResult[i] = doctorName;
            }
            return doctorNamesResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String doctorJsonString = null;

            try {

                final String BASE_URL = "http://mycityortho.com/display_result.php";
                final String NAME_PARAM = "name";
                final String STATE_PARAM = "state";

                URL url = null;
                if (params[0].equals(doctorName)){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(NAME_PARAM, params[0])
                            .build();
                    url = new URL(uri.toString());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, url.toString());
                }else if (params[0].equals(selectedStateValue)){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(STATE_PARAM, params[0])
                            .build();
                    url = new URL(uri.toString());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, url.toString());
                }

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                doctorJsonString = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, doctorJsonString);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return parseDoctorName(doctorJsonString);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            if (result != null){
                doctorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(DoctorNameActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
                listView.setAdapter(doctorAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is it crashing? the stack trace of the exception would help.

Comment: Please share exception/error logs.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are sending only one value in intent that is "State Name" or  "Name" but in other activity you are trying to receive both value, that why you get null pointer exception. 
So use the following code to solve this error.

```
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!selectedStateValue.equals(" ") || doctorName.equals(" ")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PatientSectionActivity.this, DoctorNameActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("State Name", selectedStateValue);
                        intent.putExtra("Name", " ");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (!doctorName.equals(" ") || selectedStateValue.equals(" ")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PatientSectionActivity.this, DoctorNameActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("State Name", " ");
                        intent.putExtra("Name", doctorName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
```